# Get latency with fping command

Tags: 14.04, ping

Is it possible to get the latency/RTT value with the fping command? I have tried the following:

```
~# fping askubuntu.com
```

All I am getting is:

```
askubuntu.com is alive
```

The reason I want to use fping is because I need to run ping in bulk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-c` and give a number of pings to send to each host:

```
fping -c 10 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2  ...
```

What does `-c` do?

```
  -c n Number of request packets to send to each target.  In this mode, a
        line is displayed for each received response (this can suppressed
        with -q or -Q).  Also, statistics about responses for each target
        are displayed when all requests have been sent (or when
        interrupted).
```

Example:

```
$ fping -c 5 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.50
192.168.1.1  : [0], 84 bytes, 1.56 ms (1.56 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.50 : [0], 84 bytes, 2.01 ms (2.01 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.1  : [1], 84 bytes, 1.39 ms (1.47 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.50 : [1], 84 bytes, 4.69 ms (3.35 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.1  : [2], 84 bytes, 2.06 ms (1.67 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.50 : [2], 84 bytes, 2.79 ms (3.16 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.1  : [3], 84 bytes, 1.97 ms (1.74 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.50 : [3], 84 bytes, 32.6 ms (10.5 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.1  : [4], 84 bytes, 1.41 ms (1.67 avg, 0% loss)
192.168.1.50 : [4], 84 bytes, 8.74 ms (10.1 avg, 0% loss)

192.168.1.1  : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 1.39/1.67/2.06
192.168.1.50 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 5/5/0%, min/avg/max = 2.01/10.1/32.6
```

The numbers in the summary line show you the response times you want. If you only want the summary and not the ping-by-ping report, use `-q -c`. If you want to then process the result with a script (i.e. you want something easy to parse), use `-C` instead, it will give you just the numbers separated by spaces.

I learned about this very easily by doing `man fping`. Remember, `man` is your friend :)

Comment: I did look into `man` but failed to notice the `-c` parameter :) Thanks.